# Nvidia GPUDirect and camera capturing to GPU

Tags: directx, gpu, nvidia, gpudirect

I have a USB3 camera, and I need to have the captured images to be loaded into DirectX texture. Currently I'm just doing it in my code in the user mode - grab images and upload them to GPU, which is, of cause, certain overhead on CPU and delay of ~5-7 milliseconds.

On a new PC there's Nvidia Quadro GPU card, which supports `GPUDirect`, as I understand, this allows faster memory sharing between the GPU and the CPU, but I'm not sure how can I take advantage of it. In order to capture the images directly to GPU buffers, does the camera driver need to support it? Or it's something I can configure in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is wrong

> as I understand, this allows faster memory sharing between the GPU and
>   the CPU

GPUDirect is NVIDIA Technology to support PCI to PCI transfers between devices and not between CPU and GPU. In fact it removes a CPU copy while transferring data between 2 PCI devices.

For utilizing GPUDirect in your case you need to have a capture card which will be connected via PCI (your camera will be connected to capture card). Then you can transfer frames Directly to GPU.

Can't comment if it will be faster than USB transfer.